# How to turn these Taylor series into combinations of elementary functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I am using c and k as variables, where $c,k\in\mathbb{N}$. The sums that I need to find are:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{cn+k+1+\lfloor nm/c\rfloor} (x)^{cn+k}}{cn+k}},$$ $$m\in\mathbb{Z}, m<c$$
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \frac{(cn+k)m}{c}\rfloor} (x)^{cn+k}}{(cn+k)!}}$$
$$h(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(x)^{cn}}{cn}}$$
For g(x), making c=1 or c=2 does give an elementary function, cosh(x) or exp(x),
f(x) is a part of ln(x) and g(x) is based off of e^x/cos(x)/sin(x).
Could someone show me how to find these functions? Any help would be awesome!

Comment: If you just want the answers, have you tried Wolfram|Alpha or similar? It spits out (c) at least

Comment: I forgot about that feature!

Comment: For $f$ and $g$, you can get answers for specific values of $c$ and $k$ in terms of [Hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) by asking [Mathematica to do it at TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@4NDdaQ9dQM07DVCtP20LbUFOrAsrW1NeAMjR1qvN0DHQ889Iy8zJLKmtj9fUDijLzSv7/BwA). As an aside, note that even values of $c$ make the $(-1)^{cn}$ irrelevant.

Comment: Yes. That is on purpose. I’ll look at that.

Comment: Ok, you can use `FunctionExpand` to get it written in terms of (complex) elementary functions, as in [this TiO example](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@4NDdaQ9dQM07DVCtP20LbUFOrAsrW1NeAMjR1qvN0DHQ889Iy8zJLKmtj9fUDijLzSv7/BwA). If there's something you need that TiO can't address, please edit your question with clarification.

Comment: I think that the Wikipedia article [Series multisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection) has some answers.

Comment: @MarkS.. For $f(x)$ no ptoblem foa any $(c,k)$. The problem of $g(x)$ seems difficult.

Comment: @Somos thank you! That helped a lot!

Comment: Fixed! I did need the old equation, but that has been solved. Thank you

Comment: I seem to have written g(x) wrong too! I fixed it though!

Comment: Thank you for informing me about the multisections @Somos . $f(x)$ is a multi section of $e^x$, $g(x)$ is a combination of multisections of $e^x$ and $h(x)$ diverges (if it did not diverge it would be a combination of multisections of $\ln(x)$